# How to write Unicode string to file with UTF-8 BOM by C++?

Tags: c++, encoding, stream

I can use ofstream to write to UTF-8 BOM file. I can also write Unicode string to file using wofstream and imbue with `utf8_locale` (`codecvt_utf8`). However, I cannot find out how to write Unicode string to file with UTF-8 BOM encoding.

Comment: `utf-8` does not need `BOM`.

Comment: @axiac: it doesn't need it, but it can help. In an ideal world all text would be accompanied by a MIME-type. Since this is not an ideal world, a BOM in a UTF-8 file helps software guess the encoding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15914558/1599699

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example below works fine in VS 2015 or new gcc compilers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>

int main()
{
    std::string utf8 = u8"日本医療政策機構\nPhở\n";
    std::ofstream f("c:\\test\\ut8.txt");

    unsigned char bom[] = { 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF };
    f.write((char*)bom, sizeof(bom));

    f << utf8;
    return 0;
}
```

In older versions of Visual Studio you have to declare UTF16 string (with `L` prefix), then convert from UTF16 to UTF8:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>

std::string get_utf8(const std::wstring &wstr)
{
    if (wstr.empty()) return std::string();
    int sz = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    std::string res(sz, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), &res[0], sz, 0, 0);
    return res;
}

std::wstring get_utf16(const std::string &str)
{
    if (str.empty()) return std::wstring();
    int sz = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), 0, 0);
    std::wstring res(sz, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &res[0], sz);
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    std::string utf8 = get_utf8(L"日本医療政策機構\nPhở\n");

    std::ofstream f("c:\\test\\ut8.txt");

    unsigned char bom[] = { 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF };
    f.write((char*)bom, sizeof(bom));

    f << utf8;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmak. I am using Visual Studio 2013 and get error in "u8" literal because VS2013 cannot understand it. I know it worked on VS2015 but I want to do it on VS2013.

Comment: I don't remember VS2013 capabilities. See the updated code, it should work for older compilers.

Answer (score 4):

BOM is just first optional bytes at the beginning of the file to specify its encoding. it has nothing to do directly to `std::fstream` as `fstream` is just a file stream for reading and writing random bytes/characters.

you just need to manually write the BOM before you continue writing your utf8 encoded string.

```
unsigned uint8_t utf8BOM[] = {0xEF,0xBB,0xBF}; 
fileStream.write(utf8BOM,sizeof(utf8BOM));
//write the rest of the utf8 encoded string..
```

Comment: Or if you're using a wide stream with the locale doing the UTF-8 encoding then it's just character `U+FEFF`

Comment: @SteveJessop UTF-16 Big Endian : `FE FF` Little Endian `FF FE`

Comment: @Dieter that's the byte sequence. The unicode code point is (regardless of endianness) `U+FEFF`

Comment: fstream can write BOM to file but cannot write unicode string (e.g. "日本医療政策機構" or "Phở") as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: FYI: you can also get the UTF-8 BOM with C++11 compilers by using `const char utf8Bom[] = u8"\uFEFF"`

Comment: To address @AlexHuynh's point as having the same problem, following from SteveJessop and rubenvb, when opening a std::wofstream ofs, I achieved success with "ofs << L"\FEFF";".