# Write a string with binary mode vs text mode

Tags: c++, binary, fstream

What's the difference with following codes:

**Code #1: Using Binary Mode**

```
int main()
{
    std::fstream w("D:\\file.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    char *p = "Hello World\r\nHi";

    w.write(p, strlen(p));

    // Close the file
    w.close();
}
```

**Code #2: Using Text Mode**

```
int main()
{
    std::fstream w("D:\\file.txt", std::ios::out);

    char *p = "Hello World\r\nHi";

    w.write(p, strlen(p));

    // Close the file
    w.close();
}
```

Does it matter whether I use binary or text mode in case of writing strings like this?

Comment: Since it looks like you're using Windows, in text mode `'\n'` gets written as the two characters `'\r' '\n'`.

Comment: The files will be different on windows because of the processing of `\n`. Look at it in a hex editor.

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows 8.1.

Comment: In my code, I am using `w.write(..` for binary and text mode. Does it matter?

Comment: The duplicate question has C code not C++.

Comment: Yes there will be differences as we said. The duplicate I linked also mentioned other differences.

Comment: `c` and `c++` are the same in this respect.

Comment: @drescherjm: for writing and reading unicode text files, do i need binary mode?

Comment: No you don't need binary mode for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911141/writing-unicode-to-a-file-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you're working with text, bits represent text data, but in binary, bits represent custom data (not only text, but audio, image and etc). If you intend to work with text, I'd suggest you to use text mode, since it'll be less prone to get corrupted and easier to use with other applications.